# perl hex() analog in python

Tags: python, perl, hex

perl hex() analog in python how to?
I have next perl code:

```
my $Lon = substr($Hexline,16,8);
say $output_f "Lon: " . hex($Lon) . "";
```

where `$Hexline` has "6a48f82d8e828ce82b82..." format

I try it on python

```
Lon = int(Hexline[16:24], 16)
f.write('lon = %s' % str(Lon)+'\n')
```

is it right?

EDIT: in perl's case hex() gives me a decimal value.

Comment: what happens when you run that? Use the python CLI, it's your friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, to convert an hexadecimal string to an integer you use `int(hex_str, 16)`.

Note that in your `write` method call:

- You don't need to concatenate two strings to add the new line character, you can add it to the formatting string directly.
- To print integer you should use `%d` instead of `%s`.
- You don't really need to call `str` to transform the integer into a string.

Hence, the write call could be written as:

```
f.write('lon = %d\n' % Lon)
```

Alternatively, you could also use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec) this way:

```
f.write('lon = {0}\n'.format(Lon))
```

Comment: Thank you! Format that's all i need.

Comment: If you insist on using %d in %-formatting, shouldn't you insist on using 'd' in str.format as well? :)

Comment: @ThomasWouters I agree on that the examples aren't symmetric. However, in the first case I find a little bit misleading using `%s` (`int.__str__` is called), while in the second case I find that not using a specific type isn't against the way format should be used (`int.__format__` is called).